# Where are the line breaks in this php code?

Tags: php, dreamweaver, line-breaks

This is probably pretty basic but can someone tell me where the line breaks are in this php script? I've been told to 'remove the line breaks between the field tags'.
thanks!

```
<td class='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'>
 <label for='<?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(); ?>'><?php echo wpsc_checkout_form_name();?></label>
```

Comment: the line breaks are the wpsc_checkout_form_element_id(). Look inside that function

Comment: i'm pretty new to php - I have the script open in dreamweaver but how do i go about looking inside that function?

Comment: I don't see any linebreak, can you post what `wpsc_checkout_form_name()` has inside? Unfortunately I have no idea how dreamweaver works, you'll have to google it.

Comment: If you 'are asked to' remove those breaks while you are pretty new to PHP, I assume there's a team leader there who can point to to the right code? For us, from here it's a little hard to name the file and line number to search for.

Comment: unfortunately not - i'm on my own, been asked over the web. I'd post the whole script but its over 500 lines of code. I'd also post what wpsc_checkout_form_name() has inside but have no idea where to go about looking for that!

Comment: It seems to be a function from the eCommerce plugin for WordPress. The source code is [here](http://www.8tiny.com/source/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-includes/checkout.class.php.source.html#l172).